# Two-way data binding with nested ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a proper answer component and i can use it this way

```
[(answer)]="answer"
```

It is all okey with fire event and it does work.
The Question object contains the Anser[]. And when i try to use it:

```
<answer *ngFor="let answer of question.Answers" [(answer)]="answer"></answer>
```

I receive exception

> Cannot assign to a reference or variable! ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!(…) Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

Anyone have an idea why is throw exception.

**answer.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'answer',
    templateUrl: 'answer.component.html',
})
export class AnswerComponent extends ComponentBase implements OnInit {
    @Input() answer: Answer;
    @Output() answerChange: EventEmitter<Answer> = new EventEmitter<Answer>();

    private _isToggled: boolean;
    @Input() set isToggled(value: boolean) {
        this._isToggled = (value === undefined) ? false : value;  
    }

    get isToggled() {
        return this._isToggled;
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.requestMaterialDesignUpdate();
    }


    toggle() {
        this.isToggled = !this.isToggled;
        this.requestMaterialDesignUpdate();
    }

    answerTextChanged(input: any) {
        this.answerChange.emit(this.answer);

    }

    markAnswerAsCorrect(event: Event) {
        this.answer.IsCorrect = !this.answer.IsCorrect;
        this.answerChange.emit(this.answer);
    }
}
```

**answer.component.html**

```
<div class="display-flex-nowrap textbookDetailsContainer">
    <div class="padding-2rem answerBorderLeft cursor-pointer width100">
        <header (click)="toggle()" class="answerRowOrder">
            <div>
                <i *ngIf="!isToggled" class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>
                <i *ngIf="isToggled" class="material-icons">arrow_drop_up</i>
            </div>
            <span class="part-text" [innerHTML]="answer.Text"></span>
        </header>
        <div *ngIf="isToggled" class="padding-2rem">
            <ckeditor rows="3" [(ngModel)]="answer.Text" (change)="answerTextChanged($event)" name="answer" [config]="{ extraPlugins: 'justify,image2,divarea',  removePlugins: 'about'}"></ckeditor>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="padding-2rem answerBorderRight checkboxBigSize">
        <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect float-left">
            <input type="checkbox" class="mdl-checkbox__input" [checked]="answer.IsCorrect" (change)="markAnswerAsCorrect($event)">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code for the answer component.

Comment: Beside your problem, it's not recommended to use double data binding when passing data to child. You should rather use events and register on it from your answer component. like `<answer *ngFor="let answer of question.Answers" [answer]="answer" (onAnswerChange)="handleSomeLogicFunction()"></answer>`

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer updated with code

Comment: @Maxime For example you can use [(ngModel)] and (change) at the same time. What is going wrong to use for example [(answer)] instead of [answer] and (answerChange)? And i didn't see any advice in tutorials about passing data to child.

Comment: @Maxime Why do you think double data binding is not recommended? It's perfectly fine to do that (with or without `ngModel) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#two-way

Comment: I guess the problem is the binding to the `*ngFor` variable. Can you try to bind to a property of the component instead?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer without *ngFor is working perfectly. But how to deal then with *ngFor?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it's fine to use double data binding but as far as I understand, it's better to pass data top to bottom and event bottom to top. So if you use it in your current template, use double data binding but otherwise prefer input/output to create components with APIs.

Comment: Double data binding **is** passing data top to bottom and event bottom to top. It's just syntactic sugar for `[childProp]="parentProp" (childPropChange)="parentProp = $event"`

Comment: See a related issue for Angular - [Support two-way bindings to the item of ngFor](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19819)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work

```
<answer *ngFor="let answer of question.Answers let idx=index"
    [(answer)]="question.Answers[idx]"></answer>
```

Comment: Sorry, had a redundant `s` before `[idx].answer`

Comment: I get work it in this way `<answer *ngFor="let answer of question.Answers let idx=index" [(answer)]="question.Answers[idx]"></answer>`. But why angular didn't understand just simple way [(answer)]="answer"?

Comment: Sorry, seems I was a bit sloppy reading your code. `[(answer)]="answer"` is syntactic sugar for `[answer]="answer" (answerChange)="answer = $event"` but it is not supported to assign a different value to a `*ngFor` variable.

Comment: Is way to make it work with syntax sugar :? I have tried to add NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, to my component, cause i wanted to use [(ngModel)], and it does throw the same exception.

Comment: I don't think there is a way around. It would work if `answer` is an object and you bind to `[(answer)]="answer.value"` or `[(ngModel)]="answer.value"` so that you don't directly reassign the `*ngFor` variable.

Comment: I found out that if we input object to child component, we actually send reference of our current object. Than we don't need two-way data binding and we can write `<answer *ngFor="let answer of question.Answers" [answer]="answer"></answer>`. Every change of answer inside AnswerComponent will change original object.

Comment: See a related issue for Angular - [Support two-way bindings to the item of ngFor](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19819)